# display 'last modified' on a single article page, SP online

Tags: sharepoint-online, publishing-page

I need to display on a few article pages so I do not need the code to be placed in the page layout or in the master page. Is this possible?

The model is what appears on the Enterprise wiki page on top.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `FieldValue`  in your publishing page layout.

Demo:

```
<div id="page_information">
            Page last modified:<SharePoint:FieldValue FieldName="Modified" runat="server" id="modified" ControlMode="display" /></div>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I did not write I need it on every page, I just need it as a script on some pages

Comment: Create a custom page layout, the page which need display the time, use the page layout. Otherwise, I think you need JavaScript code to display this information dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below mentioned code in a script editor webpart.

Create some html as:

`<span id="modifiedDate"></span>`

After that, add jQuery reference and then run the below code:

```
function getModifiedDate(){
    var itemId = _spPageContextInfo.pageItemId;

    $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Pages')/items?$select=Modified&$filter=ID eq " + itemId,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json;" },
            success: function (data) {        
                console.log(data.value.Modified);
                $("modifiedDate").html("Page Modified on: " + data.value.Modified);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
     getModifiedDate();    
});
```

Comment: where do I place the big code above? does it matter that the column name is "Modified" and the internal name for Modified is LastModifiedTime?

Comment: Place it in a Script editor webpart, add jquery reference first and then add this code in `<script>` tags. The column name is Modified

Comment: I added this as a jquery reference <script src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script> with your code in between and it didn't display anything, and what is the relation of the line you posted above the code? (the span one)

Comment: the rest call will fetch the modified data and add it to the span tag. You might need to work on the styling part

Comment: so I put the rest call and span line in the same script editor? what jquery reference I need to add?

Comment: also, will this work on Wiki Pages and Article pages equally?

Comment: Yes, first the span html, then <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> and then my code inside <script></script> tags. Yes, will work on Wiki and article pages as well

Comment: I have placed the above code and I see nothing, see original message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82075/discussion-between-gautam-sheth-and-susan).